# Fork and printf()

Tags: fork

So my output for the code below includes printing D twice, and I can't seem to understand why. It'll be great if someone could explain it to me.

```
int main() {
    int r = fork();
    printf("B\n");
    int t = fork();
    printf("C\n");
    if(r == 0) {
        printf("D\n");
    } else if (r > 0 && t == 0){
        printf("E\n");
    }
    printf("F\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: First `fork()` created a child. Second `fork()` created a child from parent and a child from the first child (grandchild). Parent process will have `r > 0` therefore it will not print `D`. The child process forking another child, both will have `r==0` though only one of them will have t==0. Summary, both original child and grandchild printed `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use naming convention to easily describe how the code runs. Let's call the parent that executes `X=fork()` `Xparent` and the forked child `Xchild`. Parents end up with `X > 0` and child with `X==0`.

You have a parent that executes `r=fork()` and `t=fork()` making it an Rparent and a Tparent.

We now know that Rchild will have `r==0` and Tchild will have `t==0`.

However, the older child, Rchild, executes `t=fork()` making it a Tparent and forking a Tchild.

The Tchild forked by Rchild will have `r==0`, memories from parent and child are cloned.

Hence you end up with Rchild having `r==0` and its child having `r==0`. Two processes printing `D`.